# How to convert the 'dtype = object' NumPy array into 'dtype = float' array?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra, sympy

This problem is caused by using SymPy to find reduced row echelon matrix, I have screen capture below. By using SymPy, I can get a NumPy array of object, it is quite confusing for me here. First, I don't see numbers in the rref matrix is wrapped by ' ' or " "，how come they are 'object'. Second, is there any way to convert it into a 'dtype = float' np.array?

```
M = sy.Matrix([[4, 0, 11, 3], [7, 23, -3, 7], [12, 11, 3, -4]]) 
M_rref = M.rref()
M_rref = np.array(M_rref[0])
M_rref.astype(float)
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: thanks! I will follow the rules next time!

Comment: What about this time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short answer:

`M_rref.astype(float)` will fix your problem.

#### Long answer:

Why does this happen?

In order to find out, try going back to your matrix `M` and try the following:

```py
>>> print(M[0])
>>> print(type(M[0]))
```

You will get:

```
4
sympy.core.numbers.Integer
```

That's why. Even though it *says* it's 4, it's actually a SymPy **object** that is stored inside the SymPy matrices. And that's the way it should be: SymPy is for symbolic mathematics. Therefore, when you convert it to a numpy array, NumPy will recognize `sympy.core.numbers.Integer` as an object.

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: @Flyingpig added some more information to help you understand.

Answer (score 0):

In this [PR](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/18911) there is a note about incorrect conversion of numpy matrices to SymPy matrices. Using that (and not `float`, which I don' think is intended to convert contents of an object to floats) I would do:

```
>>> sy.Matrix(M.rows, M.cols, [sympify(x) for x in M_rref]).n()
```

This should give you a SymPy matrix with entries evaluated as floats.