# assign a dtype to each colum of a numpy array

Tags: arrays, numpy, casting

I'm trying to cast a dtype for each column of a numpy array but I'm having no luck.
I tried some solutions find on stackoverflow (for example using `astype()` function for each column as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60776967/how-to-convert-the-dtype-object-numpy-array-into-dtype-float-array) or trying to declare explicitly the datatypes with `np.array(..., dtype = [])` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66892150/how-to-set-the-dtype-of-each-column-of-a-numpy-array) but nothing worked...

In particular for the second solution, if I try this code

```
with open('posizioni_mm.txt') as f:
    a, b, c, d, e  = [x for x in next(f).split()]
   
    dt = [('A', 'int'), ('B', 'float'), ('C', 'float'), ('D', 'float'), ('E', '<U32')]

    array = np.array([([x for x in line.split()]) for line in f], dtype = dt )
```

I obtain this error

`ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'link_2'`

as the array is shifted by one column (the 'link_2' should be column E and its dtype should be string but it is put in column D), and if I try to generate the array without datatypes and then an empty array with correct dtypes

`array2 = np.zeros(np.shape(array), dtype = dt)`

it generates an array with 5 tuple of 5 element for each row

```
[[(0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '')
  (0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '')]
 [(0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '')
  (0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '')]
 [(0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '')
  (0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '')]
 [(0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '')
  (0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '')]
 [(0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '')
  (0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '')]
 [(0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '')
  (0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '')]
 [(0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '')
  (0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '')]
 [(0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '')
  (0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '')]
 [(0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '')
  (0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '')]
 [(0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '')
  (0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '')]
 [(0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '')
  (0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '')]
 [(0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '')
  (0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '')]
 [(0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '')
  (0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '')]
 [(0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '')
  (0, 0., 0., 0., '') (0, 0., 0., 0., '')]]
```

what's wrong?

EDIT:
this is the content of the file posizioni_mm.txt

```
30 0.78 227.31 270.7 link_1
30 0.73 310.79 268.72 link_2
30 0.32 141.41 276.87 link_3
35 0.45 72.47 212.11 link_4
30 0.18 163.22 205.95 link_5
8 0.25 109.69 207.49 link_6
24 0.3 295.15 197.14 link_7
45 0.3 390.97 179.96 link_8
8 0.45 153.08 101.1 link_9
33 0.36 87.44 114.32 link_10
8 0.24 285.9 94.27 link_11
30 0.42 326.87 90.97 link_12
33 0.4 221.15 96.92 link_13
18 0.2 257.49 56.61 link_14
51 0.16 194.71 53.96 link_15
```

Comment: can you share `'posizioni_mm.txt'` link (or contents)?

Comment: yes, sure, it's in the edit

Comment: *as the array is shifted by one column* - you should actually check that. Write `print([([x for x in line.split()]) for line in f])` in place of the `array =` line for a test.

Comment: If you specify dt = [('A', 'int'), ('BCD', 'float', (3,)), ('E', '<U32')]`, then the `np.zeros`, or `loadtxt` array will have 3 fields, one integers, one strings and the other floats.  `arr['BCD']` will be a (n,3) array.

Comment: `loadtxt` or `genfromtxt` with `dtype=None`, will automatically deduce field dtypes.  You still get the 1d structured array.  Another idea is to use `usecols` to load all columns except the last (string one).  The rest can be loaded as floats, and you can do your 'math' freely

Answer (score 0):

Use [`numpy.loadtxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt) for simple load data from a text file:

```
with open('posizioni_mm.txt') as f:
    dt = [('A', 'int'), ('B', 'float'), ('C', 'float'), ('D', 'float'), ('E', '<U32')]
    arr = np.loadtxt(f, dtype=dt)
    print(arr)
```

---

```
[(30, 0.78, 227.31, 270.7 , 'link_1') (30, 0.73, 310.79, 268.72, 'link_2')
 (30, 0.32, 141.41, 276.87, 'link_3') (35, 0.45,  72.47, 212.11, 'link_4')
 (30, 0.18, 163.22, 205.95, 'link_5') ( 8, 0.25, 109.69, 207.49, 'link_6')
 (24, 0.3 , 295.15, 197.14, 'link_7') (45, 0.3 , 390.97, 179.96, 'link_8')
 ( 8, 0.45, 153.08, 101.1 , 'link_9')
 (33, 0.36,  87.44, 114.32, 'link_10')
 ( 8, 0.24, 285.9 ,  94.27, 'link_11')
 (30, 0.42, 326.87,  90.97, 'link_12')
 (33, 0.4 , 221.15,  96.92, 'link_13')
 (18, 0.2 , 257.49,  56.61, 'link_14')
 (51, 0.16, 194.71,  53.96, 'link_15')]
```

---

Now you can access a column by name, for ex. `'E'`:

---

```
print(arr['E'])
```

---

```
['link_1' 'link_2' 'link_3' 'link_4' 'link_5' 'link_6' 'link_7' 'link_8'
 'link_9' 'link_10' 'link_11' 'link_12' 'link_13' 'link_14' 'link_15']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but then I need to manipulate the data in the matrix, in particular I need to comput mean and std deviation of data in column B.
Before loading the 'link_' name i was able to use these commands on numpy (float) array
```
groups = np.split(array[:, 0:], np.cumsum(np.unique(array[:, 0], return_counts=True)[1])[:-1])
group_stats = np.array([(g[0, 0], len(g), np.mean(g[:, 1]), np.std(g[:, 1])) for g in groups])
```
but now they doesn't work.

Comment: In particular I can create groups modifiying first line with
`groups = np.split(array['A'], np.cumsum(np.unique(array['A'], return_counts=True)[1])[:-1])`
but i cannot manage to modify accordingly the second

Comment: With a `compound dtype` like `dt` you can create a `structured array` (that is well documented).  While nice for loading a csv, you can't do math across the fields of such an array.  The array is 1d, with fields, not columns.

Comment: I'd suggest asking another question demonstrating what you want to do with the `groups`.  Maybe have an example with a 2d float array, and then one (possibly failed) with a structured array.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the data in an array, it's easy to calculate the mean and standard deviation for a field (column). This answer shows how to extend the solution posted by @RomanPerekhrest above.

```
f = 'posizioni_mm.txt'
dt = [('A', 'int'), ('B', 'float'), ('C', 'float'), ('D', 'float'), ('E', '<U32')]
arr = np.loadtxt(f, dtype=dt)
col_B = arr['B'] # to load column B values to an array
print(f"Col B mean = {np.mean(col_B):.2f}") # reference col_B above
print(f"Col B stddev = {np.std(arr['B']):.2f}") # Or just use arr['B']
```

Printed values for your data:

```
Col B mean = 0.37
Col B stddev = 0.18
```

Answer (score 0):

For copy-n-paste convenience I substitute a list of strings for your file:

```
In [27]: txt = """30 0.78 227.31 270.7 link_1
    ...: 30 0.73 310.79 268.72 link_2
    ...: 30 0.32 141.41 276.87 link_3
    ...: 35 0.45 72.47 212.11 link_4
    ...: 30 0.18 163.22 205.95 link_5""".splitlines()
```

Your compound dtype:

```
In [28]: dt = [('A', 'int'), ('B', 'float'), ('C', 'float'), ('D', 'float'), ('E', '<U32')]
```

To create a structured array from data, you need to provide a list of tuples (not a list of lists).  With a minor change your code works:

```
In [29]: np.array([(tuple([x for x in line.split()])) for line in txt], dtype = dt )
Out[29]: 
array([(30, 0.78, 227.31, 270.7 , 'link_1'),
       (30, 0.73, 310.79, 268.72, 'link_2'),
       (30, 0.32, 141.41, 276.87, 'link_3'),
       (35, 0.45,  72.47, 212.11, 'link_4'),
       (30, 0.18, 163.22, 205.95, 'link_5')],
      dtype=[('A', '<i4'), ('B', '<f8'), ('C', '<f8'), ('D', '<f8'), ('E', '<U32')])
```

And the same thing with loadtxt/genfromtxt:

```
In [30]: data = np.loadtxt(txt,dtype=dt)    
In [31]: data
Out[31]: 
array([(30, 0.78, 227.31, 270.7 , 'link_1'),
       (30, 0.73, 310.79, 268.72, 'link_2'),
       (30, 0.32, 141.41, 276.87, 'link_3'),
       (35, 0.45,  72.47, 212.11, 'link_4'),
       (30, 0.18, 163.22, 205.95, 'link_5')],
      dtype=[('A', '<i4'), ('B', '<f8'), ('C', '<f8'), ('D', '<f8'), ('E', '<U32')])

In [35]: data['A']
Out[35]: array([30, 30, 30, 35, 30])
```

I can't tell what you are trying to do with groups.  Just remember with a structured array, you have fields, not columns.  So 2d indexing doesn't work.  You can't, in general, do math across fields.

It's possible to define a dtype that groups the 3 float columns together:

```
In [36]: dt = [('A', 'int'), ('BCD', 'float',3), ('E', '<U32')]    
In [37]: data = np.loadtxt(txt,dtype=dt)    
In [38]: data
Out[38]: 
array([(30, [7.8000e-01, 2.2731e+02, 2.7070e+02], 'link_1'),
       (30, [7.3000e-01, 3.1079e+02, 2.6872e+02], 'link_2'),
       (30, [3.2000e-01, 1.4141e+02, 2.7687e+02], 'link_3'),
       (35, [4.5000e-01, 7.2470e+01, 2.1211e+02], 'link_4'),
       (30, [1.8000e-01, 1.6322e+02, 2.0595e+02], 'link_5')],
      dtype=[('A', '<i4'), ('BCD', '<f8', (3,)), ('E', '<U32')])        
In [40]: data['BCD']
Out[40]: 
array([[7.8000e-01, 2.2731e+02, 2.7070e+02],
       [7.3000e-01, 3.1079e+02, 2.6872e+02],
       [3.2000e-01, 1.4141e+02, 2.7687e+02],
       [4.5000e-01, 7.2470e+01, 2.1211e+02],
       [1.8000e-01, 1.6322e+02, 2.0595e+02]])
```

Or load all the numeric columns as float, skipping the string one.  This gives 2d float array:

```
In [41]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt,usecols=[0,1,2,3],encoding=None)
In [42]: data
Out[42]: 
array([[3.0000e+01, 7.8000e-01, 2.2731e+02, 2.7070e+02],
       [3.0000e+01, 7.3000e-01, 3.1079e+02, 2.6872e+02],
       [3.0000e+01, 3.2000e-01, 1.4141e+02, 2.7687e+02],
       [3.5000e+01, 4.5000e-01, 7.2470e+01, 2.1211e+02],
       [3.0000e+01, 1.8000e-01, 1.6322e+02, 2.0595e+02]])
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i didn't know how to create an array of tuples but the answer was very simple :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to you all, I solved the issue in a very inelegant way but... it works

In short I use massively .astype(...) method to convert (temporarily) the string into int or float

1. after creating the array from the file .txt I use argsort with astype(int) for array[:,0]

```
with open(file) as f:
    
    array = np.array([[x for x in line.split()] for line in f])

array = array[array[:, 0].astype(int).argsort()]
```

2. then I operates on array[:,1], computing mean and std with .astype(float)

```
groups = np.split(array[:, 0:], np.cumsum(np.unique(array[:, 0].astype(int), return_counts=True)[1])[:-1])
group_stats = np.array([(g[0, 0], len(g), np.mean(g[:, 1].astype(float)).round(2), np.std(g[:, 1].astype(float)).round(2)) for g in groups])
```

3. and then I use group_stats for other things (I have to choose the 3 classes which have a cumulative confidence level >0.35 and a std deviation < 0.2)